# TYPO3 v9.5 Extbase Error Handling with routeEnhancers

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

In my Extbase TYPO3 Extension I want to show a custom fluid template when the record is not available anymore (hidden or deleted). The error handling loads a fluid template where the path is defined in the setup.typoscript.

But when I add the routEnhancers in site config.yaml file for my Extension then the Error handling doesnt work anymore and it just shows the default TYPO3 Error Page: "The requested page does not exist".

In the docs of the site config I didn't find any way to set a special error handling for my Ext.

Here is the Code that handles it so far:

Controller:

```
class RecordController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController
{


    /**
     * Error handling if no entry is found
     *
     * @param string $configuration configuration what will be done
     * @throws \InvalidArgumentException
     * @return string
     */
    protected function handleNoRecordFoundError($configuration)
    {
        $statusCode = HttpUtility::HTTP_STATUS_404;
        HttpUtility::setResponseCode($statusCode);

        $this->getTypoScriptFrontendController()->set_no_cache('Record record not found');

        $standaloneTemplate = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(StandaloneView::class);
        $standaloneTemplate->setTemplatePathAndFilename(GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName($configuration));
        return $standaloneTemplate->render();
    }

    /**
     * @return TypoScriptFrontendController
     */
    protected function getTypoScriptFrontendController()
    {
        return $GLOBALS['TSFE'];
    }
    /**
     * action show
     * @param \Digitalgizmo\Vehicles\Domain\Model\Vehicle $vehicle
     * @return void
     *
     *
     */
    public function showAction(\Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Record $record = null)
    {

        if ($record !== null){

            $this->view->assign('record', $record);
        }
        else {
            $errorContent = $this->handleNoRecordFoundError($this->settings['show']['errorTemplate']);
            if ($errorContent) {
                return $errorContent;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

config.yaml;

```
routeEnhancers:
  MyExt:
    type: Extbase
    extension: MyExt
    plugin: MyExt
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/staticName/{uid}/{slug}'
        _controller: 'ControllerName::show'
        _arguments:
          slug: record
          uid: id
    defaultController: 'ControllerName::show'
    aspects:
      slug:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_domain_model_record
        routeFieldName: slug
        routeValuePrefix: /
      uid:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_myext_domain_model_record
        routeFieldName: uid
```

The RoutEnhancer works just fine if the record is available.

How can I catch that error, so I can handle it and show my fluid template? My showAction isn't even being loaded (tested with XDebug). I assum this is because the TYPO3 core throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to j4k3

I've created my own aspect type for the routeEnhancers, which removes the deleted and hidden constrains, so it won't throw an error.

I followed this documentation to create it: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html

Here is my CustomMapper Class.

```
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\ConnectionPool;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\QueryBuilder;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\DeletedRestriction;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\FrontendGroupRestriction;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\FrontendRestrictionContainer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Database\Query\Restriction\HiddenRestriction;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Routing\Aspect\PersistedAliasMapper;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;


class CustomMapper extends PersistedAliasMapper
{
    protected function createQueryBuilder(): QueryBuilder
    {
        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
            ->getQueryBuilderForTable($this->tableName)
            ->from($this->tableName);
        $queryBuilder->setRestrictions(
            GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FrontendRestrictionContainer::class, $this->context)
        );
        // Frontend Groups are not available at this time (initialized via TSFE->determineId)
        // So this must be excluded to allow access restricted records
        $queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeByType(FrontendGroupRestriction::class);
        $queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeByType(DeletedRestriction::class);
        $queryBuilder->getRestrictions()->removeByType(HiddenRestriction::class);
        return $queryBuilder;
    }
}
```

Basically the only thing I added was the removal of the DeletedRestriction and HiddenRestriction.

Further more I had to change the Slug field how it gets built. I added the uid of the dataset to the slug and removed the separate uid GET Parameter, so now the slug is unique in the database. Before I did that I had the problem that the query found multiple of the same slug values and it always took the first one.

And now since the slug is unique in the database table it will return the object and wont throw an error, so I can handle the "error" in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Everything seems fine with that code, the problem is that the RouteEnhancer is affected by the same constraints as your showAction: once the record is deleted, the resolve method in the routeEnhancer will no longer be able to find it nor its slug.

As a reference, see the resolve function in the API: https://api.typo3.org/9.5/_persisted_alias_mapper_8php_source.html . It instanciates a queryBuilder which, by default, builds a deleted=0 clause.

To get deleted redcords by their slug, what you need to do is build a custom RouteEnhancer, maybe by extending the PersistendAliasMapper class in a way that it also finds deleted records, refer https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Routing/ExtendingRouting.html , but be aware of the implications: the slug field in your model will no longer be able to find colliding slugs even with the eval=uniqueInSite option set because that, too, only sees non-deleted records.